# Is there any way to use Cookies in Shopify Liquid templates?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, liquid

I am setting up a cookie inside a script file; however, I do not seem to find any working way to grab the value of that cookie and compare it against another value using Shopify liquid if statements?

For example,

I have a cookie set as: `customer_email: 'test@gmail.com'.`

I would like to grab this cookie value somehow and compare it using Shopify's if statement as below:

```
{% if customer_email == 'test@gmail.com' %}

   DO SOMETHING

{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to read cookies from Liquid. But you can read the value client-side with JavaScript in the Liquid template.

Comment: Sorry if my response was unclear. You can take the liquid value you want to compare from the DOM and pass it in your js script to compare it to the js value. Based on that check you can append whatever results you want to the page.

Comment: You can edit your answer to make it clearer (and delete the comment) :)